# Java static initialization block

Tags: java

I saw this sample code at Oracle Certification website and someone here can explain me the concept of static {} ?

```
public class Sequence {

Sequence() {
    System.out.print("c ");
}

{
    System.out.print("y ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Sequence().go();
}

void go() {
    System.out.print("g ");
}

static {
    System.out.print("* ");
}

}
```

Comment: the `static` block will be the first block called when the class is compiled and ran. See the following : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

one with `static` keyword static initialization block not a method ,it runs when class in loaded.

the other `{}` without static is a initialization block it runs after `super()` call is made by constructor

Comment: Thanks! I'll change the title.